# Change ContentEncoding in Flask before uploading svg file to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python, svg, amazon-s3, flask, boto3

I am using Boto3 and uploading files to my Amazon AWS S3 bucket.
I am using Cloudfront which gzip files by itself on resposne as long as the server sends  ContentEncoding header.
Currently I guess it does not because when I try to see the image (I upload an SVG image) I get an error:  ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILD

How can I add this header to the file when uploading?

Comment: *"I am using Cloudfront which gzip files by itself on resposne as long as the server sends ContentEncoding header."*  That isn't correct, for multiple reasons.  Where did you read this?

Comment: When auto compress is handled of course: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront

Comment: Yes... except that it says, *"The response **must not** include a `Content-Encoding` header."* (emphasis added)

Comment: Yeah I saw it later. So currently my response includes a ContentLength header, no Content-Encoding header and compressing on CloudFront is turned on. How can I check it is actually sending a compressed file when the browser auto decompress it when I load the page?

Comment: If the response header seen at the browser includes `Content-Encoding: gzip` (this is added by CloudFront when it gzips the response) and the browser renders the object correctly (no error) then CloudFront gzipped the response.  Be sure you do an [invalidation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) and let it finish before testing.